# Spark DataFrameReader from RedShift tempDir dump

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift, databricks

Is there a way to create a DataFrame from a tempDir dump from RedShift?

My use case is when a job fails, I want to retry but continuing from the temporary data dump that was dumped to S3 rather than re-fetching the dataset all over again from RedShift which is HUGE!

The load code does this

```
val df1 = spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
  .option("url", jdbcUrl)
  .option("dbtable", spmeTable)
  .option("tempdir", tempDir)
  .option("user", jdbcUsername)
  .option("password", jdbcPassword)
  .option("forward_spark_s3_credentials", true)
  .load();
```

The job later on fails, but I want to recreate df1 without fetching anything from RedShift again.

Is there a way to do this?

Found a method called `createDataFrame` under SparkSession, not sure if that is a possible solution...
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html

**UPDATE #1**

the temp dir looks like the directory structure here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD_command_examples.html

I opened one of the temp files from S3 and it is pipe delimited

```
edd66540-fa17-599b-9b22-7df29a5f9229|kNOCugU4wuKAUw7m2UXS7MfX|2018-11-27 19:48:44|POST|f|@NULL@|@NULL@|@NULL@|@NULL@|https://www.example.com/r/conversations/0grt6540-
```

**UPDATE #2**

According to this
https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/tree/master/tutorial

Once the files are written to S3, a custom InputFormat (com.databricks.spark.redshift.RedshiftInputFormat) is used to consume the files in parallel. This class is similar to Hadoop's standard TextInputFormat class, where the key is the byte offset of the start of each line in the file. The value class, however, is of type Array[String] (unlike, TextInputFormat, whose type is Text). The values are created by splitting the lines using the default delimiter (|). The RedshiftInputFormat processes the S3 files line-by-line to produce an RDD. The schema obtained earlier is then applied on this RDD to convert the strings to the proper data types and to generate a DataFrame.

Any idea how to do all that but skipping the unload?

Answer (score 1):

The connector dumps the data in **avro** format by default([Can be dumped in CSV, CSV GZIP format as well](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift#parameters)).
Also note that the connector does not automatically clean the temporary location([check the Note](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift#authenticating-to-s3-and-redshift)).
We could read the data by pointing to the `tempdir`

```
val df = spark.read.format("avro").load(tempdir)
```

Comment: I tried this, getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException: No Avro files found. If files don't have .avro extension, set ignoreExtension to true`, I opened one of the temp files and it looks like some sort of a pipe delimited format

Comment: @AssafMoldavsky Did this work for you in the end?